# How can I get only the outer markup of an XML element?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, outerxml

If I have an `XmlNode` like this

```
<element attribute="value">
    Content
</element>
```

I can get its `InnerXml` ("`Content`"), but how can I get the opposite? That is, just the outer markup separated by its opening tag and closing tags:

```
<element attribute="value">
```

and

```
</element>
```

I want to exclude the inner xml, so the `OuterXml` property on the `XmlNode` class won't do.


Do I have to build it manually by grabbing each piece and formatting them in a string? If so, besides the element's name, prefix and attributes, what other property can XML elements come with that I should remember to account for?

Comment: Removing all child nodes may be easier (definitely will produce more correct XML), may need to copy whole node first if you can't change document.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you correctly all you want is `OuterXml` without `InnerXml`. In that case you can take the outer XML and replace the content with an empty string.

```
var external = xml.OuterXml.Replace(xml.InnerText, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try either of these two options if you don't mind changing the xmlnode:

```
foreach(XmlNode child in root.ChildNodes)
    root.RemoveChild(child);

Console.WriteLine(root.OuterXml);
```

Or

```
for (int i=0; i <root.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
  {
    root.RemoveChild(root.ChildNodes[i]);
  }
```

Note:

```
//RemoveAll did not work since it got rid of the xml attributes which you wanted to preserve
root.RemoveAll();
```